# PostgreSQL: Performance Tuning a Query

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-optimization, postgresql-11

I have a tables like below:

Table Name: **Table_A**

| A_ID | A_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 21 | XYZ |
| 22 | IJK |

Table Name: **Table_S1**

| S_ID | S_Name | A_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | ABC123 | 21 |
| 124 | PQR321 | 22 |

Table Name: **Table_S2**

| S_ID | S2_Date_1 | S2_Date_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01/01/2015 | 02/04/2016 |
| 124 | 01/01/2021 | 02/04/2018 |
| 123 | NULL | 02/04/2019 |
| 124 | 01/01/2017 | NULL |

Table_A and Table_S1 have primary keys and where as Table_S2 has no primary key.

Table_S1.A_ID --> is referenced to --> Table_A's Primary Key A_ID

Table_S2.S_ID --> is referenced to --> Table_S1's Primary Key S_ID

There are about 400,000 records in Table_S1 table and each record in Table_S1 has 120 records referenced from Table_S2. Which means Table_S2 is a huge table having around 48 million records.

I have a requirement to fetch Years from Table_S2's S2_Date_1 and S2_Date_2 columns individually using 2 different queries like below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM s2.S2_Date_1)
  FROM Table_S2 s2, Table_S1 s1, Table_A a
 WHERE s2.S_ID = s1.S_ID
   AND s1.A_ID = a.A_ID
   AND s1.B_ID = b.B_ID
   AND a.A_Name = 'IJK';
```

If I group by A_ID, records would be like below:

| A_ID | Count_of_Table_S1 | Count_of_Table_S2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | 100,000 | 12,000,000 |
| 22 | 150,000 | 18,000,000 |
| 23 | 90,000 | 10,800,000 |

There are no partitions made on Table_S2. It is taking around 1min to fetch all the years from these millions of records, my requirement is to fetch them in a second. Is this possible to do this?
Can anyone please suggest a best way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query, ideally after setting `track_io_timing = on`.

Comment: You don't seem to need any columns of the joined tables, rewriting the ancient implicit joins to an EXISTS condition might improve performance.

Comment: You will not be able to dynamically summarize that many records in a second.  Use a materialized view.

Answer (score 0):

You have a great many rows to summarize. Getting this down to one second, reliably, may not be possible.

You can try putting a stored generated column on `Table_S2`, then indexing it.

```
ALTER TABLE Table_S2
 ADD COLUMN S2_Date1_Year 
            GENERATED ALWAYS AS EXTRACT(YEAR FROM s2.S2_Date_1)
            STORED;
```

That gives you the column.  Then

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_S2 ADD INDEX year_by_sid (S_ID, S2_Date1_Year);
```

adds the index.  Then change your query to

```
SELECT DISTINCT s2.S2_Date1_Year ...
```

It's possible, but not certain, that your query will be faster: it doesn't have to recompute the year on each row.

You may want a materialized view instead.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW View_S2_Year AS
SELECT DISTINCT S_ID, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM s2.S2_Date_1) AS S2_Date1_Year
  FROM Table_S2;

CREATE INDEX year_by_sid ON View_S2_Year (S_ID, S2_Date1_Year);
```

Then join that View_S2_Year rather than Table_S2.

Note:  You'll need to refresh the view once in a while to bring it back in sync with its base table. Its contents will be stale after changes to the base table until you refresh it.

```
REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW View_S2_Year;
```

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. I'll try in these ways and see if I can make it as simple as you have mentioned. Will share the result here again. :)